# Why Android cannot deal with Resources name conflict between Project and Library?

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a project A that referenced by Library B, A and B have the same name and type, but their value are different. I think aapt should deal with this issue that make sure project and library access the correct value. besides renaming all the resource in project or library, what else should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The classpath of `A` and `B` should be different. Isn't it?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Classpath and package is different

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The build system intentionally makes all project resources overlay on top of the library resources. This is done on purpose to be able to customize a library resource differently depending on the app using it.

If you want to prevent this happening without your knowledge we have always recommended users to use prefix in the library resources.

Changing the behavior at this point would break many, many people's projects. We've looked at making it an option, but it won't happen before the new build system is finished though.

Comment: I think it should be an option. Suppose that a library has thousands of resources that do not have prefix, we cannot make sure name conflict would not happen.

Comment: I agree, and we have taken steps to make it possible in the new build system. There's more work required though.

Comment: BTW, why aapt cannot gather stuff in assert dir of library into apk?

Comment: We added this to the new build system. It's done outside of aapt though to allow for better control. For instance we could make it overlay (current behavior to match resources), or have an option to fail on duplicate assets like we are talking about for resources.

Comment: hi @XavierDucrohet is this still the case today? thanks

Comment: "we have always recommended users to use prefix in the library resources."- can you link that please?

Comment: To avoid resource conflicts, use non-transitive (https://developer.android.com/build/optimize-your-build#use-non-transitive-r-classes) R classes. If this is not possible, then consider using a prefix or other consistent naming scheme that is unique to the module (or is unique across all project modules). This is the default behavior in Android Gradle plugin 8.0.0 and higher.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Android Building process](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html), all projects and libraries (and all of the resources in all of them) are combined as part of the apkbuilder process. If there is a conflict between your project and library (or between two libraries), the final build will not know which to reference as they share the same name. Of course, this has benefits in that you can reference library resources in your project by name, even though the underlying build process is de-conflicting the underlying ids.

Comment: so what you mean is I should rename all the resource that conflict in Project or Library? There are thousands of resources to be renamed! OMG!

Answer (score 0):

Import the appropriate R.java file to resolve the resource conflicts.

1. Make sure that your package name and the library's package names are different.
2. If you need your libraries resources then refer to them by `library.packagename.R.drawable.resourceId` and not by `R.drawable.resourceId`
3. Check your gen files if it has 2 R.java files.

Comment: 1. package is definitely different. 2. library.packagename.R.drawable.resourceId and R.drawable.resourceId are the same when compiled by aapt

Comment: 3. gen dir has 2 R.java and they are in different packages

Comment: then just follow 2. Refer your resources by packagename.R.drawable.resourceID.

Comment: No matter what resources you reference, it is R.drawable.resourceId. It is overwritten by aapt.

Comment: Code is fine, you can't do it in the XML: e.g. `@com.foo.bar:string/foo` isn't valid.

Comment: To avoid resource conflicts, use non-transitive (https://developer.android.com/build/optimize-your-build#use-non-transitive-r-classes) R classes. If this is not possible, then consider using a prefix or other consistent naming scheme that is unique to the module (or is unique across all project modules). This is the default behavior in Android Gradle plugin 8.0.0 and higher.