# Resource entry activity_horizontal_margin is already defined

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my android project I'm using few libraries. The point is when I'm adding a new one, for example:

```
compile(group: 'com.example', name: 'example_sdk', version: '+', ext: 'aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

And trying to build the project I'm getting the next output error from gradle :

> D:\AndroidStudioProject\MyProject\res\values-w820dp\dimens.xml
>   Error:(2) Resource entry activity_horizontal_margin is already defined.
>   D:\AndroidStudioProject\MyProject\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.example\example_sdk\3.2.7\res\values-w820dp-v13\values-w820dp-v13.xml
>   Error:(2, 1) Originally defined here.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':processMyAppUniversalDebugResources'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Tools\Android_SDK\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My guess is that in some libraries we have default defined values-w820d/dimen.xml and they are conflicting. But the question is how to merge them, because the key is the same.

```
values-w820d/dimen.xml content :
<resources>
<!-- Example customization of dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml
     (such as screen margins) for screens with more than 820dp of available width. This
     would include 7" and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp respectively). -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
```

When I rename the `activity_horizontal_margin` to `activity_horizontal_margin_default` - conflict is solved for my project, but conflicts appears with other libraries.
Maybe I can add some gradle-override property or modify the gradle script to ignore this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time I was asking this question, I had already made a workaround. I had two conflicting libraries with default defined `activity_horizontal_margin` values inside`values-w820d/dimen.xml` . So as one of the libraries was local .aar - I unziped it and removed the conflicting file, after that zipped it back and the problem was solved. This approach is not so elegant - but it worked for me. I was waiting for better solution, but it didn't come. So such kind of mess should be handled by the library developers. And here is a usefull answer by Xavier Ducrohet :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16351116/3874721