# Drawable picked from library instead of my project

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, r.java-file

I have dependency on a library, which has `ic_launcher.png`[for all densities] as drawable. My project also has `ic_launcher.png` for all densities].

I reference the drawable in xml. It works in api level 23,16. I have galaxy tab api 19. It picks up the `ic_launcher` from the library.

I tried to clean and build. But the issue remained.

How to fix this issue? Apart from the workaround of renaming my drawables.

Comment: Are you sure that you have an `ic_launcher` for every density that the library does?

Comment: I had put my mdpi resource in drawable folder and not in drawable-mdpi. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You might want to read the answer here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350957/why-android-cannot-deal-with-resources-name-conflict-between-project-and-library